# xterm font color (and ubuntu rgb.txt)

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, colors, xorg, xterm

I tried  `xterm -fg gray` and `xterm -fg grey` but both gave `Warning: color name... is not defined`.

I am on ubuntu and there is no rgb.txt in /etc/X11/rgb.txt

How can I launch xterm with custom fg/bg colors? (specific rgb values).

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find a copy of the file [here](http://cvsweb.xfree86.org/cvsweb/xc/programs/rgb/rgb.txt?rev=1.2&content-type=text/vnd.viewcvs-markup).

You can also add this line to `~/Xdefaults`:

```
xterm*foreground:   gray
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there an alternative if one doesnt have root access?

Comment: actually, for now, I have root access. I copied the file, but it still does not recognize the color definitions in rgb.txt

Comment: @jp19: Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Xorg no longer uses rgb.txt for color names, but builds the color database into the X server when it's built.   The rgb.txt built into the X server comes from the app/rgb module upstream, and the upstream version can be viewed in [their git viewer](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/rgb/tree/rgb.txt).

To specify colors by value, see the ["COLOR NAMES"](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man7/X.7.xhtml#heading11) section of the [X(7) man page](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man7/X.7.xhtml).
For instance, these should each be gray:

```
xterm -bg rgb:80/80/80
xterm -bg '#808080'
```